# Solving seemingly easy differential EQ

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation $2\frac{d^2\phi}{d^2\zeta}=e^{-\phi}$, where $\phi=\Phi/\sigma_z^2$, $\zeta=z/z_0$. I also have the fact that $ln(\rho/\rho_0)=-\Phi/\sigma_z^2$. Given the boundary conditions $\phi(0)=0=\frac{d\phi}{d\zeta}\big{|}_0$, we need to show that the solution is $\rho(z)=\rho_0sech^2(\frac{z}{2z_0})$. I show below what seems to be the correct method, but I cannot reproduce the quoted answer:

$$\frac{d^2\phi}{d^2\zeta}=\frac{e^{-\phi}}{2}$$

$$\frac{d\phi}{d\zeta}-\frac{d\phi}{d\zeta}{|}_0=\frac{e^{-\phi}}{2}\zeta+c_1$$

$$\frac{d\phi}{d\zeta}=\frac{e^{-\phi}}{2}\zeta+c_1$$

to get $c_1$:
$$\frac{d\phi}{d\zeta}|_0=\frac{e^{-\phi(0)}}{2}\zeta+c_1$$
$$0=\frac{e^{0}}{2}\zeta+c_1$$
thus $c_1=-.5\zeta$

$$\frac{d\phi}{d\zeta}=\frac{1}{2}\zeta({e^{-\phi}}-1)$$

$$\frac{d\phi}{({e^{-\phi}}-1)}=\frac{1}{2}\zeta d\zeta$$

letting $u\equiv e^{-\phi}-1,du\equiv -d\phi e^{-\phi}\rightarrow du\equiv -d\phi (1+u)$. thus this becomes
$$\int-\frac{du}{(1+u)u}=\int\frac{1}{2}\zeta d\zeta$$

I use the partial fraction method to beget the LHS in a tractable form, and integrating this equation I get the following:

$$-ln(1-e^{\phi})+ln(1-e^{\phi(0)})=\frac{\zeta^2}{4}+c_3$$

$$-ln(1-e^{\phi})-\infty=\frac{\zeta^2}{4}+c_3$$

$$-ln(1-e^{\phi(0)})-\infty=\frac{\zeta^2}{4}+c_3$$

$$\infty-\infty=\frac{\zeta^2}{4}+c_3$$
so $c_3$ is supposedly $-\zeta^2/4$.

This is problematic, for then I get that $\rho/\rho_0=0$. What may be leading it astray?

Comment: $\phi=\phi(\zeta)$ is a function here

Comment: Ok, someone was faster than me!

Answer (score 3):

You have
$$2\phi''=e^{-\phi}$$
Multiplying by $\phi'$ you get the integrable equation
$$2\phi'\phi''=e^{-\phi}\phi'$$
When integrated, this yields
$$(\phi')^2=-e^{-\phi}+C$$
which is separable.

Comment: @user4437416, no, the 2 goes away in the integration (think of the power rule for integration).

Comment: You have to integrate the entire left hand side, not just the derivative.

Comment: Yes, certainly. Thank you, I have acquired it.

Answer (score 1):

Your first integration is wrong since $\phi=\phi(\zeta)$ is not a constant.

P.S.

In case you didn't know, this equation is closely related to [Liouville's DE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_equation).

Answer (score 1):

You're given the solution $\phi(\zeta) = -\ln(\text{sech}^2(\zeta/2))$ , you just have to verify that it satisfies the differential equation and initial condition.  Just plug it in, simplify and see that both sides come out equal.

Comment: Thank you Robert. Of course one may check the permission of this solution form, but I wished to know how we may derive it without taking it as ansatz